# Django best practice - compare users

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a small project and I have a user profile page.

This page has a variable called **user**.
This variable contains the user object of the current profile page.
The logged in user object is accessible with **request.user**

If you just print the user object it will return the username because the model returns this in the `__str__` function

What is the best way to compare if the user profile belongs to the current user?

I could just write

```
if user == request.user
```

But what if django changes the return value of the `__str__` function?

or I could write

```
if user.username == request.user.username
```

or

```
if user.id == request.user.id
```

Comment: why do you want to compare user against user. you can simply use request.user for profile

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta.. there are situations when we have to compare them... like to provide a option for edit the profile, and so on!

Comment: It depends what your `user` actually is. If it is a model instance of the same type as `request.user` then the simple `==` between the objects is the right way to compare. Django will take care of the right internal comparison operations. If it is from an other type you have to make the right comparison on your own, for example comparing the `username` attribute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`if user == request.user:` is the correct way. Comparison is based on database primary keys, not on string representations. Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#comparing-objects

Answer (score 4):

Roman Miroshnychenko answered the question already, just a small addendum:

Looks like the question originated because you assumed that `==` comparison would internally call the `__str__` function. This is not the case.

The `__str__` method is sometimes called implicitly, but only in well defined places, like:

- by the print function in `print(obj)`
- by string formatting in `'{0}'.format(obj)` or `f'{obj}'` or `'%s' % obj`

There's also the `__repr__` method that is called implicitly in other places, such as after each value in Python interactive shell:

```
>>> a = SomeObject()
>>> a
<__main__.SomeObject object at 0x7f5f218889e8>
```

However the `==` operator doesn't touch any of that and calls the `__eq__` method instead. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think that `if user.pk == request.user.pk` will be the best practice, because every user have different PKs(Primary Keys), so there will be no chance of any mess in your web app.

Comment: Of course this only matters if you're writing an re-usable app. In a typical Django project you know and can depend on particular shape of User model.

Comment: Django models already compares using pk, so the correct test is `user == request.user`